# What happens when I set the second argument of getFileName() to false?

Tags: php, zend-framework

In the following statement, If the second argument is set to FALSE will the statement return the filename along with its full path?? Or what will it do? thanks.

```
$filename = $uploader->getFileName(NULL, FALSE);
```

Comment: Because looking it up in the docs or searching on google - or god forbid trying it - didn't cross your mind, eh? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [zend documentation 19.1.4](http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Framework/zend.file.html):

> getFileName() accepts the name of the element as first parameter. If no name is given, all known filenames will be returned in an array. If
>   the file is an multifile, you will also get an array. If there is only
>   a single file a string will be returned.
>
> Per default filenames will be returned with their complete path. **If
>   you need only the filename without path, you can set the second
>   parameter $path which will truncate the filepath when set to false.**

In simple english; settings the second parameter to false will make `getFileName` return the filename without it's path.

If it will normally return *`/internet/stackoverflow/question_8555785.txt`* it will only return **`question_8555785.txt`** when the second parameter to the function is `false`.

Comment: @MichaelRader No problem, glad to be of service.